# Board Game algorithms

Tags: game-theory, board-games, computer-games

I have to  find an  evaluation function  in which   we evaluate the state of the  game in each round.

The  game is  like  " roborally "  ,  it is 2 player-Game in which there are  a board and  cards that decides my movements on each  cards  there is  number of translations , number or rotations.The goal of the game is to  get  all the Flags before the other player does ( there are 4 Flags). \

each player recives 9 cards and can only play 5 cards in one round  and each field have  some special effects ( some are positive and some are negative), so i must find a heuristic that evaluates the movement  i will play. the question how can i find such function .

[image: Game board]

The colored fields are the  original  board game ,  the  white  fields are only virtual. \

Let  s say we are on the field (6.0) and  we want to go further ( out of the original board) then we lend to (6.13) which is  virutal, but then  we will  go to the real (6.13)  here is an example .
[image]

let  say that i am standing on filed (5.12) and the  flag is on field(4.0)
how to use the function to decide in which order  should i play the 5 cards and  which 5 cards from  the 9 cards  should i play

[image]

is there any related   game algorithms that might help to find a solution for my problem .

Comment: What sort of movements can you do, exactly? Do you know which movement cards you'll get in advance? When is a path 'shortest'? Minimum number of cards? Distance between the fields? Minimal distance actually traveled?
Also, your title can be improved. It would help if you can edit it to more specific to this problem, rather than a general title.

Comment: acually the game is kinda more complicated  , and yeah i  recieve  9 cards and i have to play  only 5 cards ,  each card has (r,t,f) with r is number or  rotation ( the play will make r  rotations ) and number of translations and  f the number  or field rotation .i must find a good heuristic  to evaluate each   card i paly ( the  goal of the game is  to conqure 4 Flags ( flags are distributed on the field) ,thus finding the shortest path is still only an idea which i think is not correct

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to think about your problem and ask a better question.

Comment: yeah i will  edit it

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Since the question doesn't fully specify the game, I doubt that we have enough information to give you a solution.  But I don't think the question will be interesting if you fully specify the game; it seems too complicated and messy to be interesting.  Instead, it sounds like it would be more useful to ask about some concept (something that will be useful in other contexts / other games too) rather than just asking for a solution for this specific game.  (continued)

Comment: What research have you done on AI techniques for playing games?  Have you read about alpha-beta search?  Have you read about Monte Carlo Tree Search?  Have you read about how people  construct heuristic evaluation functions in the context of other games (e.g., chess, checkers, connect 4, and so on)?  Have you read about using machine learning to learn an evaluation function?  Have you read about reinforcement learning, especially as applied to games?  There are many techniques out there.  I think you'll do better if you study the basics and use that to help you ask a more focused question.